# Naming a function getTaxonomyId makes my app to crash, all other names are fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot 2 app, using Spring Data on an Oracle Database and the following issue happens in an entity.

First of all, I was trying to code the following:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "taxonomy_id")
public long getTaxonomyId()
{
    return taxonomy.getId();
}
```

And noticed the app wouldn't start (Using Intellij play button which does a maven srpingboot:run if I'm not mistaken).

Removed **@JsonProperty**, changed the **return to 1**. Still not working.

Changing the function name to anything else works (Like getTaxonomyID for example) and setting it to private also makes the app start again.

The only thing I'm getting before the crash is this:

> 2019-01-24 10:30:09 INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
>
> 2019-01-24 10:30:12 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
>
> 2019-01-24 10:30:12 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
>
> 2019-01-24 10:30:12 INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
>
> 2019-01-24 10:19:51 WARN  o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [sacs] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>
> java.base@10.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>    app//oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:327)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I've tried looking for other usages of this name anywhere else but this is the only place to be found.

So, any clue? I'm particularly interested in knowing why this is happening, since fixing it can be done by just chaging the name even though this one is the most appropiate and documenting this weird behaviour for the next one to come.

**Update 1**: After debugging a bit:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppLauncher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mOracleDataService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleDataService' defined in file [C:\myApp\OracleDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List myApp.repository.CategoryRepo.findByTaxonomyId(java.lang.Long)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [taxonomyId] on this ManagedType [myApp.entity.TreeStructure]

So, a bit of context here: **getTaxonomyId** is in the **Category** class. Both **Category** and **Taxonomy** extend **TreeStructure** which is an *abstract class*:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class TreeStructure<T extends TreeStructure>
{
    public abstract long getId();
    // [...]
}
```

So it seems my **getTaxonomyId** is somehow colliding with the one in **CategoryRepo.findByTaxonomyId(java.lang.Long)**? Even weirder: It seems to be looking for the **taxonomyId** in the **TreeStructure** instead of in the **Category**

**Update 2:** Indeed changing *findByTaxonomyId* to *findByTaxonomy_Id* fixed the issue.

So it seems that Spring, when I created the getter **getTaxonomyId** and trying to create the **findByTaxonomyId** query thought **taxonomyId** was a member from the **Category** (even though it was not declared as one) and that's why it failed to create it?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: The error you mention is pretty generic. Try to debug it, and set the debugger to stop on exception throwing.

Comment: Could you show the rest of the class? so we can see what taxonomy is

Comment: @Dilyano Senders Taxonomy is actually an other entity and this class holds an instance of it.

Comment: @reallynice yeah I know it's pretty generic so I couldn't find much infor about it, I'll try debugging deeper.

Comment: is taxonomy declared as a field within the class? If not it cannot be accessed

Comment: @DilyanoSenders Yeah it is, I'm using it many times already.

Comment: @reallynice I think that I found the issue, even though I think this behaviour is quite crazy.